# Odoo 16 call ir.actions.client from python code

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I want to play an audio file according to a certain logic. To do this I created a JS function and a Python function for my model.

```
odoo.define('konstanta.play_audio', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var core = require('web.core');

    function playAudio(audioFileUrl) {
        const audio = new Audio(audioFileUrl);
        audio.play();
    }

    core.action_registry.add('play_audio', function (action, options) {
        const audioFileUrl = options.params['audioFileUrl'];
        playAudio(audioFileUrl);
    });
});
```

and i create pyhon func

```
def play_audio_file(self, filename):
    action = {
        'type': 'ir.actions.client',
        'name': 'play_audio',
        'tag': 'play_audio',
        'target': 'new',
        'params': {
            'audioFileUrl': filename,
        }
    }
    return action
```

When I call this action on the button click, everything works, the audio file is played. But when I call this function from the backend part, the audio file is not played. How to fix this? Tried to implement this through controllers and python requests library, but that also fails.

I expect that when running an automated script in my backend logic, a call to this function should play an audio file.